# PHP: How do I remove some tags when parsing an HTML page?

Tags: php, parsing, xpath

When parsing a part of a webpage(from a < div > with "parse-it" id), I'd like to get removed < script > tags and, what's more, 'href' attributes from < a > tags from there. Here you are my code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*[starts-with(@id, "parse-it")]') as $childNode) {
$result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}
echo $result;
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

UPD: document example: https://jsfiddle.net/azt97tm4/

Comment: Do you want to do it the hard way with PHP/DOM interfaces, or the easy way with XSLT? Either way, we need to see what the document looks like before and after the change.

Comment: Here you are a document example: https://jsfiddle.net/azt97tm4/ before and after parsing it looks the same

Comment: I'd prefer the way with PHP/DOM interfaces

Comment: Fine, no problem, but I can't advise then because I would never do it that way myself.

Comment: Ok. And how would you get it done with XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ( $xpath->query('//div[starts-with(@id, "parse-it")]//script') as $badScriptNode) {

    $badScriptNode->parentNode->removeChild($badScriptNode);
}

foreach ( $xpath->evaluate('//div[starts-with(@id, "parse-it")]//a[@href]') as $badAnchorNode) {

    $badAnchorNode->removeAttribute("href");
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with STR_Replace.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```html
$result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
$target = array("<script>", "www.example.com");
$modify   = array("", "google");
$output = str_replace($target, $modify, $result);
}
echo $output;
```

Try this. If any problem ask me.

Comment: Manipulating XML or HTML at the lexical level using regular expressions is nearly always a bad idea. Your code will almost inevitably have bugs, which will only show up in production when you try it on a document that it wasn't tested on; it may also have very poor performance.

Comment: Edit: It works for links and href attributes all around the page. As for < script > tags, they stay unremoved.

Comment: normally should work. or remove content of < script > tags. finally like that < script > < / script> . possible

Comment: If no long - content of script

Comment: Michael Kay , Really very poor performance some webpages reason big datas. What can we do another? Be available another way?

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT code removes all script elements and a/@href attributes from an XML document. I've used XSLT 1.0 here, because although XSLT 3.0 makes it a little shorter (and is available for PHP by installing the relevant Saxon library), XSLT 1.0 is still more widely used by PHP users.

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- default template copies everything unchanged -->

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- drop script elements -->

<xsl:template match="script"/>

<!-- drop a/@href attributes -->

<xsl:template match="a/@href"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Note that XSLT (like XPath) is defined to operate on XML rather than HTML, so you may need to do an initial conversion - I don't know the PHP world well enough to know the details. You may also need to make changes if the source document uses namespaces.